# While concatenating multiple properties for adding under one column is not working in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I Have a search box under that HTML table is there.I am trying to implement auto complete search.It is working fine .I want to concatenate vndr_address,state and pincode and show under address column.I tried but it is giving null [image]like below screen shot.How to do that please help me .Thanks in Advance.

```
    $(function() {
        $("#search").keyup(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url();?>Vendorcontroller/search",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: value
                },
                success: function(response){
                var data=$.parseJSON(response);
                    var tbody = $('#myTable tbody').empty();
                    tbody = $('#myTable  tbody'),
              //I have concatenate coulmns like this it is giving null
                    prop = ["vndr_name","vndr_address"+','+"state"+'-'+"vndr_pincode","vndr_mobile","vndr_telephone","vndr_mailid"];
                    $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                      var tr = $('<tr>');
                      $.each(prop, function(i, prop) {
                      $('<td>').html(data[prop]).appendTo(tr);
                      });
                     $('<td>').html("<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>Vendorcontroller/edit/"+data["vndr_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
                     $('<td>').html("<a class='delete'href='#?id="+data["vndr_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
                      tbody.append(tr);
                });
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: So your data has a property `vndr_address,state-vndr_pincode` or does it have 3 separate properties `vndr_address`,`state` and `vndr_pincode`?

Comment: Those are three separate properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an array containing the data properties to populate the cells, the problem is that `vndr_address,state-vndr_pincode` is not a property of your data object.

You could fill the prop array with the data you're going to put in the cell instead of the property of the object.

```
$.each(data, function(i, data) {
    prop = [data["vndr_name"],data["vndr_address"]+','+data["state"]+'-'+data["vndr_pincode"],data["vndr_mobile"],data["vndr_telephone"],data["vndr_mailid"]];
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $.each(prop, function(i, prop) {
        $('<td>').html(prop).appendTo(tr);
    });
    $('<td>').html("<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>Vendorcontroller/edit/"+data["vndr_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
    $('<td>').html("<a class='delete'href='#?id="+data["vndr_id"]+"'><i class='fa fa-remove fa-2x'></i></a>").appendTo(tr);
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it is working fine if matched records are there showing records but if record not match it is showing empty.I want to show no results found instead of empty,How i can i do that Please help me.